# Why is the form not being displayed?

Tags: ajax, django

I am using django and ajax to submit a form, but when the form is invalid then it's not been displayed.

```
# views.py
class ProductCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Product
    template_name = "products/my_products.html"
    form_class = AddNewProductForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        obj = form.save(commit=False)
        obj.user = self.request.user
        obj.save()
        return JsonResponse({"msg": "Your product was created successfully."})

    def form_invalid(self, form):
        return render(self.request, "products/add_new_product.html", {"form": form}, status=400)


saveNewProductButton.on("click", function () {
        var addNewProductForm = $(".add-new-product-form");
         $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/product/new/',
        data: addNewProductForm.serialize(),
        success: function(res){
            alert(res['msg']);
            location.reload();
        },
         error: function (res) {
            var newProductPlaceHolder = $("#new-product-form-placeholder");
            newProductPlaceHolder.html(res);
         }});
    });
```

The res is shown in the console using Chrome, but not on the page.

Comment: `form_class` shuld be class, not instance. Try this `form_class = AddNewProductForm`.

Comment: @neverwalkaloner I corrected it but it didn't change anything.

Comment: You are using different template in form_invalid. Check if `form` variable using in `"products/add_new_product.html"`.